# Encounters error in conversion from varchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert `varchar` to `float`, but I get an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float

This is the code details that encounters error:

```
declare @per varchar(10) = '10.21%';

print substring(@per, 1, len(@per) - 1);

set @str = 'select top 1 ' + cast(substring(@per, 1, len(@per) - 1) as float) + ' as ColumnA from #TempSui' ;

exec (@str);
```

Comment: by the way, why do you need to select from #TempSui table when the only column you are returning is the @per value ?

Answer (score 0):

your this statement `substring(@per,1,len(@per) -1)` extract the numbers without the % and then you convert to float

and after that you are trying to concatenate a string `select top 1` with a floating point number. that causes the error.

remove the cast() and it should be good

```
set @str = 'select top 1 ' + substring(@per,1,len(@per) -1) + ' 
AS ColumnA from #TempSui' ;
```

EDIT :

```
set @str = 'select top 1 ' + 'CAST ( ' + substring(@per,1,len(@per) -1) 
     + ' AS FLOAT) AS ColumnA from #TempSui' ;
```

EDIT 2:
not sure what is the purpose of the #TempSui table, if you just need to convert @per to floating point number, you can do this

```
SELECT  CAST(substring(@per,1,len(@per) -1) AS FLOAT);
```

Comment: I just wanna convert varchar to float. if remove cast, it have not expected

Comment: I want float, but for now it is string and the format is 'xx.xx%', so I extract without '%' first, then convert to float.

Comment: try the 2nd query. Is this what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue at line no 3
when you are concatenating String with the float value, which is not possible in SQL server. You can concatenate only string values

Please find this screenshot for your easy reference 
[image]

Comment: I dont know your requirement but still you want to convert infloat the use this at 3rd line 
`set @str = 'select top 1 cast(' + substring(@per,1,len(@per) -1)+ ' as float)
 AS ColumnA from #TempSui' ;`

Comment: Cause the data type was varchar, and its format is 'xx.xx%', so I want use substring to extract without '%', and then convert it to float. Is there anyway to solve it?

Comment: above comment should solve your problem and still facing issue then comment here

Comment: You can also check this code if you are looking for this `SELECT  CAST(SUBSTRING(ColumnA,1,LEN(ColumnA) -1) AS FLOAT)  AS FloatColumn  FROM table1`
Here table1 contains ColumnA is varchar datatype in XX.XX% format and we are fetching this column in float datatype

Answer (score 0):

You may also do that in following  way :

```
DECLARE @per VARCHAR(10)= '10.21%';
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX);

PRINT SUBSTRING(@per, 1, LEN(@per)-1);
SELECT @per = CAST(SUBSTRING(@per, 1, LEN(@per)-1) AS FLOAT);
SET @str = 'select top 1 '+@per+' [ColumnA] from #TempSui';

EXEC (@str);
```

Result :

```
10.2
select top 1 10.21 [ColumnA] from #TempSui
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line

```
set @str = 'select top 1 convert(float,'+''''+'' + substring(@per,1,len(@per) -1)  + ''+''''+') as ColumnA from #TempSui' ;
```

Try this code:

```
 declare @per varchar(10) = '10.21%';
 print substring(@per, 1, len(@per) - 1);

 set @str = 'select top 1 convert(float,'+''''+'' + substring(@per, 1, len(@per) - 1)  + ''+''''+') as ColumnA from #TempSui' ;

 exec (@str);
```